# fgets does not prompt for user input. What is the difference?

Tags: c, string, char, stdin, fgets

I have two scenarios using fgets below.  Both scenarios are in the same file, as shown below.

```
struct sth
{
    char str[10];
    int num; 
};

void getIt(struct sth **M){ 
    char *b;
    (*M)=malloc(sizeof(struct sth));

    printf("give me an integer:");
    fgets(b,1,stdin);  // output must be an address 
    (*M)->num = atoi(b);

    printf("give me a string:");
    fgets((*M)->str,10,stdin);

}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct sth *myThing;
    getIt(&myThing);
    printf("Heres the string %s\n", myThing->str);
    printf("Heres the num \n", myThing->num);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output.  Notice that it does not prompt the user for the integer, it just prints "give me an integer", and then moves directly on to the next print statement.  Why does it do this?

```
give me an integer:give me a string:sdf
Heres the string sdf

Heres the num
```

This small problem is a larger problem in a bigger problem, so this is just a microcosm of the larger one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
fgets(b,1,stdin);  // output must be an address
```

However, `b` must be a valid address to hold the data you want to read to it. With your code, `b` is defined to be a pointer but it does not point to any valid address.

Something along the lines of:

```
char b[20]; // Make it large enough to hold the data
```

is necessary.

I am not sure why you are reading the data using `fgets` and converting it to a number using `atoi`. The other option is to use `fscanf`.

Comment: fscanf reads an unlimited number of characters, which makes it dangerous for what I'm trying to do.                    So, I chose fgets instead.               remember, this example is part of a much larger operation.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have not allocated space for `b`, `fgets()` expects it's first parameter to point to enough memory to store the result, enough being, the size you passed to it as the second parameter.
2. With the size parameter being `1`, `fgets()` is reading an empty string, you need it to be at least `3`, because `fgets()` needs space for the `'\n'` and the termination `nul`.

   So try this

   ```
   char b[3];

   fgets(b, sizeof(b), stdin);
   *M->num = atoi(b);
   ```
3. You must check that `malloc()` did not return `NULL` before trying to do anything with the pointer.